# Printing Regular expression output to excel in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have extracted the data from the response using jmeter's Regular expression extractor.Now i need to print those extracted values in excel.How to do that please help me out.I will be using multiple thread and all those output should be printed in excel as well.

Comment: Show us what you have done?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/POPm6.png . I am able to extract data from the response.Now i need title_g1 to be printed in excel

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way it to add the value to JMeter's .jtl results file, just take the next steps:

1. Add the following line to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   sample_variables=your_variable_reference_name
   ```

   or

   pass the parameter via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jsample_variables=your_variable_reference_name -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the change up
3. Next time you run your JMeter test you will see an extra column in the .jtl results file containing the variable from regular expression extractor value for each sampler

References:

- [Sample Variables Property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

---

Another approach (for example if CSV format is not suitable for some readon) would be adding [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) libraries to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) to create and/or update Excel file, but this approach is harder as you will need to avoid concurrent writes or do in in i.e. [tearDown phase](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to avoid race conditions and data loss.

See [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) for example code for working with Excel documents using Java/Groovy.

Comment: can i use beanshell preprocessor

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I would suggest going for [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/), Groovy performance is much better, it is more Java-compliant and it has some sexy language features, see [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for details.